# Does Unity 5.0 demonstrate all of the planned changes to Unity for 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04

According to the [blog post didrocks wrote](http://blog.didrocks.fr/post/Releasing-a-precise-Unity-5.0-to-Ubuntu-12.04), it is said that Unity is now frozen, except for approved changes (or something to that effect).

Does this mean that Unity 5.0 contains all of the changes for 12.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, feature freeze doesn't happen until [February 16th](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule).

Didier is [talking about](http://blog.didrocks.fr/post/Releasing-a-precise-Unity-5.0-to-Ubuntu-12.04) the soft freeze that needed to happen in order to ship Unity 5.0 in Precise.